# MS Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate - Debugger .NET Version

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I have written a Program in **C#/WPF** and the **.Net Version is 4.0**.

When I set **breakpoints** in my project I can hover over the variables in Debug-Mode and lookup all Properties and Methods of that variable.

But in Debug-Mode I still get to see the Properties of .Net-4.5, although my project is set to .Net-4.0.

For example, the [BindingExpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpressionbase(v=vs.100).aspx) Class has **different Properties** in .Net-4.0 and .Net-4.5: In .Net-4.0 the aforementioned class **DOES NOT have** the Property named ***Target*** and in .Net-4.5 the class **HAS** the Property named ***Target***.

But in my Debug-Mode I still see that Property although my project is set to .Net-4.0.

**How to change the version of the Debugger in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate ?**

or

**Am I misinterpreting the Debug-View ?**

Answer (score 4):

You are just mis-interpreting what setting the project's Target Framework version does.  You don't have .NET 4.0 on machine.  You have 4.5, you got it when you installed VS2012.  If you ever had 4.0 then it got overwritten by the 4.5 installer.  So inevitably you are going to see 4.5 properties, they are actually there and cannot be hidden from the debugger.

What you can't do is *use* those properties in your program, the compiler is going to complain.  Which ensures that your program will run correctly on a machine that only has 4.0 installed.

Comment: Ok, i guess then i have to de-install .Net-4.5 and install .Net-4.0.

Comment: Don't do that, you will break Visual Studio.  Don't solve a problem you don't have.

Comment: Yes, but i really need to look through the variables and see what is availible in .Net 4.0.

Comment: Use IntelliSense in the text editor or the MSDN Library, not a debugger.  But hey, go ahead and get this wrong the way you want it, only way to learn the ropes for some programmers.